# corrupted URLs - can't leave starting page

Tags: permalinks, database, url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules

I have a big problem with my WP installation:

An access to my pages is (no longer) possible via (public) URL. All calls that originally worked end up on the home page. Also, visitors can't get away from there anymore, for example when they click on an item from the menu. Again, you will only ever get to the home page, with the links displayed correctly.

I'm not sure if this misbehavior is related to that time we moved to a new provider or the use of the plugin WP_Landingkit. Either way, it can't stay like this and I appreciate any advice.

For a while, I was able to help myself by simply re-setting and saving the permalinks under Tools. But unfortunately this workaround doesn't work anymore.

Many thanks and best
Stefan

Comment: Does the issue go away if you deactivate your WP_Landingkit plugin? If yes, you should check with the plugin's support team; if not, contact your hosting support team.

Comment: Many thanks. No it stays same if I deactivate the plugin. What... how may the hosting support team may help? Can you give me any hint to tell them?